# Why the append method for StringBuilder class work in one package but not the another package in the same project?

Tags: java, package, stringbuilder

I have created two packages in the same project, and I tried to use StringBuilder in both packages.

However, when I try to use append method. It only works in the first package.

In the second package, it always gives me the error "The method append(String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder".

Why it would be like this?

```
'String s1 = "iPhone?";
String s2 = "what?";
StringBuilder bobTheBuilder = new StringBuilder();
bobTheBuilder.append(s1);'
```

The code is exactly the same in two files, except that the 'append' method does not work in the second package.

Comment: Is it possible you defined a **class of your own** called `StringBuilder` in the second (non-working) package?

Comment: please share the complete code.